# iOS - today extension strange error / warning

Tags: ios, widget, today-extension

In my iOS today extension (widget) I am getting this error (?) in th console during debugging

```
[Intents] __INGEOPDPlaceCreateFromCoordinate Failed to prepare place info. (placeInfo = <GEOPDPlaceInfo: 0x281cfeca0> {
}, latLng = <GEOLatLng: 0x283662d00> {
    lat = "10.0";
    lng = "13.0";
})
[Intents] __INGEOPDPlaceCreateFromCoordinate Failed to prepare component value. (componentValue = <GEOPDComponentValue: 0x10400ecb0> {
 }, placeInfo = <GEOPDPlaceInfo: 0x281cfeca0> {
 })
[Intents] __INGEOPDPlaceCreateFromCoordinate Failed to prepare component value. (componentValue = <GEOPDComponentValue: 0x10400f3f0> {
}, entity = <GEOPDEntity: 0x2804f6300> {
    name =     (
                {
            "string_value" = "Hello World";
        }
    );
})
[Intents] __INGEOPDPlaceCreateFromCoordinate Failed to prepare component. (component = <GEOPDComponent: 0x281cfeb80> {
}, componentValue = <GEOPDComponentValue: 0x10400f3f0> {
})
[Intents] __INGEOPDPlaceCreateFromCoordinate Failed to set type on component. (component = <GEOPDComponent: 0x281cfeb80> {
})
```

I dont have any idea what is this and if I should be concerned. However, widget itself seems to be running OK.

I am not able to google any usefull information regarding this.